# Updated react native to v0.6.0 - Error: Invariant Violation: Application TestApp has not been registered.

Tags: react-native

I'm getting these errors after updating react native to v0.6.0.  I even tried creating a project from scratch and I'm still getting these errors.  Has anyone else seen this?  This code was working before.  Any ideas how to fix this?

> Error: Cannot read property 'None' of undefined
>     stack: 
>                                   index.ios.bundle:24163
>          require                           index.ios.bundle:244
>                                   index.ios.bundle:23216
>          require                           index.ios.bundle:244
>                                   index.ios.bundle:1187
>          require                           index.ios.bundle:244
>                                   index.ios.bundle:1116
>          require                           index.ios.bundle:244
>          Object.ErrorUtils.applyWithGuard  index.ios.bundle:880
>          require                           index.ios.bundle:195
>     URL: undefined
>     line: undefined
>     message: Cannot read property 'None' of undefinedhandleException @ index.ios.bundle:7033
>
> index.ios.bundle:35950 Running application "TestApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. **DEV** === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
>
> index.ios.bundle:7033 Error: Invariant Violation: Application TestApp has not been registered.
>     stack: 
>          Object.AppRegistry.runApplication                      index.ios.bundle:35957
>          jsCall                                                 index.ios.bundle:7328
>          MessageQueueMixin._callFunction                        index.ios.bundle:7591
>                                                        index.ios.bundle:7618
>                                                        index.ios.bundle:7612
>          ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.Mixin.perform  index.ios.bundle:6143
>          Object.ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates     index.ios.bundle:13907
>          Object.batchedUpdates                                  index.ios.bundle:4686
>     URL: undefined
>     line: undefined
>     message: Invariant Violation: Application TestApp has not been registered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I figured out the prolblem.  It had to do with a component I was using, in my case `react-native-device`.  What I had to do to fix it was delete the `node_modules` folder located in the component. `AppName/node_modules/React-Native-Component/node_modules`.

I also updated the dependencies in the package.json file also located in the component folder `AppName/node_modules/React-Native-Component/package.json` and change the react-native dependency to (or something similar):

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-native": ">= 0.4.0 < 1"
  },
```

#### Update

You can also try restarting the computer.  I've noticed with that node starts opening multiple processes and that can cause issues.

#### Update 2

From the project root folder run in terminal:

```
./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --reset-cache
```

A combination of all the fixes above has fixed it for me.  Hope this helps someone.